# Using Autodesk Forge, How do I get dimension objects and their properties from a Revit Plan view?

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

In Revit, I have dimensions on floor plans and elevations.  I need to get at those dimensions and their properties to see if the user had overridden the value.  Is this possible using Forge?  I've only been able to get the objects and properties for items in the 3D view, not any plans, elevations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known wishlist item (`CF-4851`) in our internal case system.

Unfortunately, 2D elements such as dimensions, texts, notes, grids, and sections in plan views and elevation views are not supported by Forge MD currently. Consequently, there are no concrete elements, they aren't clickable and no object properties in the Forge Viewer as I know.

Comment: Bummer!  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Has this wishlist item been addressed and/or implemented?